# Python Daily logger with suffix for TimedRotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, logging, python-2.6

I'm new to Python and programming, and I'm trying to make a simple daily logger. I want to use `TimedRotatingFileHandler` because it fits to my needs although I can't change the suffix and that's something important. I will need my logs to use the ".csv" extension.
So I found a class `MyTimedRotatingFileHandler` which should add the suffix but unfortunately, I don't get where I'm doing mistakes.

Here is the code I'm trying to achieve, made of several snippets taken from the web.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import serial
import os
import time
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 38400, timeout=15)

class MyTimedRotatingFileHandler(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):
  def __init__(self,dir_log):
  self.dir_log = dir_log
  filename =  self.dir_log+time.strftime("%m%d%Y")+".csv"
  logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler.__init__(self,filename, 
                        when='S', interval=5, backupCount=0, encoding=None)

def doRollover(self):

   line = ser.readline()
   self.baseFilename = self.dir_log+time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")+".csv"
   self.stream = open(self.baseFilename, 'w')
   self.rolloverAt = self.rolloverAt + self.interval
   a="%s,%s,%s,%s" % (self.baseFileName,'Température :',line,"\n")
#a =  "{0},{1},{2},{3}".format(self.baseFileName,'Température :',line,"\n")
print a 
self.info(a)
#    logger.flush()
ser.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation seems incorrect, as `self` (in `self.info(a)` is not defined. You should probably indent `doRollOver` so it is a method of `MyTimedRotatingFileHandler` and then instantiate that class somewhere, call that method and check if the `print a` does then work as expected.